# How to collect binary [log] files over https from 1000+ Win/Linux machines?

Tags: elastic-stack, performancecounter, agent, trace, collect

I need to collect performance/tracing/config binary [log] files (they use proprietary formats, like winperf .BLG or sqlserverxe .XEL) over https from 1000+ Win/Linux servers distributed across public and private clouds (i.e. not in the same LAN/VPN/Active Directory). For political reasons I'm nailed to these binary formats as well as to https and I'm not allowed to transform the files on site and send out the resulting data. I can ensure the files are rolled over every ~10 minutes, to keep their sizes ~manageable (up to 100 MB with average < 10 MB).

**QUESTION:** Is there any FOSS solution out there which can be modified or is already capable of collecting all these files in a centralized location?

I'm looking for something that already covers as many as possible of these requirements:

- ensure upload channel security
- endure network outages/problems of all kinds
- pass through corporate proxies in all ways that a web browser can
- throttle upload speed based on local network usage or at least based on preconfigured limits (to avoid overloading the upload server as well as avoid local network problems induced when hogging all upload bandwidth)
- be configurable on how to select which files to upload (e.g. upload all files in a dir order by X rule except the newest file / any file modified in the last 2 minutes).

Basically, I'm looking for MS BITS on steroids, open sourced and able to run on Linux.

This is a DevOps question. The solution I'm looking for is nowhere near as simple as writing a script for wput and running it on cron. It's more like writing a custom ELK beats module or logstash variant and that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I think that ELK is the best suite you can find. Are there any reasons you're not using it for this case? Not flexible enough? Or there's no module that would not be able to read your files?

Comment: The reason is just that ELK is designed to upload a stream of small data entries (rows in files, new perf counter snapshots), not large binary files, which induce different problems (as detailed above)

Comment: If they are rolled over, how do expect to survive network outage?  Or do you have a maximum tolerance for network outage?

Comment: I'll explain with an example: Assume log_1700.blg is the latest file locked by WinPerf while it's being written to. It was created at 17:00, as its name suggests. Every 10 min it is rolled over (by a custom tool we already have) so WinPerf switches to writing to log_1710.blg. At this point log_1700.blg becomes available for upload and then it's deleted from the local server. On Windows we setup dir size quotas (or dedicated drives) for the dir where log_*.blg are written, with a generous enough amount of space to allow writes for ~3 days before hitting the quotas.